# How to view GitHub Contributors Graph for branches other than master?

Tags: graph, github

At https://github.com/yourusername/yourreponame/graphs you can find some nice graphs showing commits over time. However the information is only for the master branch.

How do I see the same information for a branch other than master, or see a graphs taking account commits across all branches?

If this is not possible, how can I at least see how many line of code have been committed under a particular branch via the GitHub web GUI?

Is any of this possible?

Comment: None of the answers work for a repo that you don't have write access to. For example, I can't figure out who the contributors are to the [Udacity Android tutorial](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine) because only the very first commit is processed, which of course, shows only one contributor.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

**Dangerous/Significant** (see comments):

I just stumble on this as well. You can actually see the graphs for other branches than the Master branch.

- On Github in your repo - choose settings.
- In settings - change your default branch to whatever branch you would like to see the graphs for.

Comment: Note that changing your default branch has significant consequences, including changing the behavior of pull requests. Details at https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/

Comment: Is there a solution for repos that are not yours? I'd like to have a look at the stats for a specific branch (which is not default) in a repo that is not mine / I have not contributed to.

Comment: While this does work, it's obviously dangerous as @Nelson said and as Paddre discovered, won't work for repos that aren't yours. I wish GitHub would add the functionality to view other branches graphs. It's probably a minor use case but I'd bet it's a minor change: add a dropdown. Based on the speed that the graph loads, I'd guess they cache the data for the default branch somewhere and so they wouldn't want to waste space by storing every branch. But they could store only the default branch (or a select few: master, develop, etc) and we would naturally expect other branches to load slower

Comment: note, gitlab supports it, eg: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/graphs/master

Comment: Not only is switch your default branch dangerous, but it is also slow in case you want to see contributions across all branches at once.

Comment: Does switching default branches, viewing the graph, and then switching back have any bad consequences if no one commits during the time it's switched or is it just clunky?

Answer (score 16):

The help of Github:  [Viewing contributions](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-contributions) :

> Whenever you commit to a project's `default branch` (or the `gh-pages` branch), `open an issue`, or propose a `Pull Request`, we count that as a contribution.

So:

- default branch
- gh-pages branch
- open an issue
- pull request

only these will be counted.

As @[Mikael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19004274/1276501) 's answer, you can change the `default branch` in repo's settings.

Another help of Github: [Which contributions are counted?](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#which-contributions-are-counted)

For commit:

> Your commit contributions are only counted when they are created on or merged into the default branch or gh-pages branch of a non-fork repository.

---

I also want github to count all the commits, not specified branch :(

Comment: I wish it had an easy way to select which branches to count.

Comment: @MarcM. yes, not way by now. I also don't know why github only count default and gh-pages branches, maybe they think other branches will merge to default branch at last.

Comment: issues or pr ok necessary but why included gh-pages branch? In most cases this branch is outside the main developer team

Answer (score 5):

From what I can see, those graphs are for `master` only: I only committed on the [branch gitlist recently](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/branches), and my [commit activity](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/graphs/commit-activity) only shows those for `master`.

Unless you rebase your branch on top of a new repo you would create specifically for that kind of inspection, said branch activity won't be visible until it is merged back in `master`.