# Get an overview of my activities on GitHub

Tags: github

I would like to see an overview of my activities (e.g., commits in several branches, issues) on GitHub to see in which periods I was busy. I tried the following ways:

- URL `https://github.com/MYNAME/REPOSITORY/commits/?author=MYNAME`, the problem is it returns only the `master` branch, while I have commits in other branches as well.
- URL `https://github.com/MYNAME?tab=overview&from=2022-02-01&to=2022-02-04`, but the following graph does not seem to show commits in the branches other than `master`:

[image]

Does anyone have any ways to get a better overview? It is not necessarily by a direct URL, I could use GitHub Desktop, command lines, or a little bit of scripts as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19004274/11231991

Comment: @GuyPorat I have commits in several branches including `master`, and I don't want to change the default branch.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, GitHub does not provide a way to see overall activity across branches in a repository, other than the default and the `gh-pages` branch - more information on https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-graphs-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile

As I haven't found anyone else resolving this, this leaves you with the option to write a piece of software that iterates through your repositories and checks the commits on all branches - introducing all kinds of challenges, such as overlapping commits and branches. Should be an interesting challenge though!